# Is it true that in Bible certain brothers are favored more than others?

Tags: nature-of-god

God favored certain brothers more than others. I want an assurance from this forum. For example God blessed Jacob's son Joseph. Samuel and not his teacher's son. We all know Cain and Abel story. David was chosen among all his siblings.

So in God's eyes certain brothers are highly favored than others by God. Is it true?

Comment: Replace "brothers" with "people" and ask yourself why they were favored, then you might see the pattern. It has nothing to do with being brothers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the beginning, God has *purposely allowed* His creation on earth and beyond to suffer the consequences of sin. He has not distanced Himself from creation, but when the time is right He will bring this age to an end and a new age will begin which makes the horrors and tragedies of this age just a *blip* in eternity.

Jesus is the centre and the reason through which all man will realise the potential that God placed inside each and every human. We are not privy to *why* God did it this way - but as we believe He is not just a God of love, He IS love, then we trust, through the pain and often terror of feeling out of control and without hope.

God does favour some over others. He chooses the people He wants to do the work needed. He is not being mean, but is exercising His sovereign will over the natural course of sin to bring about that which was planned. He allows and uses evil to bring a righteous result. We must ponder why or how the serpent was in the Garden at the beginning. Did he sneak in or was he placed in? If we say 'allowed in', that is the same as placed where God is concerned. God uses (not makes) evil to bring about good - the story of Joseph.

On the surface we understand that only through sin, could we be able to achieve, in Christ, the potential to be like He is - holy, righteous, and like that forever more - never going back to sin. He has the testament of some angels who followed Lucifer into sin and away from God.

Our understanding is limited regarding the angels and their future, but man has  choice (or *will* have each their time of choice) they may choose death and be gone forever, of life and live in the presence of God forever.

**This** life isn't supposed to be fair. The death, the trial, the trauma, the fear will all go and be replaced by something so much grander - it will be worth it.

Sadly, many have no idea of who God is or what He is doing or how  - some don't know there is a God, but each will get to have their choice free of the deception of sin and the father of all lies. We pray that day comes soon.